# How to properly import MomentJS in Typescript to resolve the following error: "Type 'typeof moment' has no compatible call signatures."

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

Importing MomentJS is causing the following error:

```
ERROR in [...] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof moment' has no compatible call signatures.
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: So MomentJS was wrongly typed in an older version? If so, installing the newest version is usually the first thing to do, not sure if that needs another answer here (might help someone having the same problem, not saying that it should be deleted, just saying ...)

Comment: just as an FYI take a look to dateFNS. momentJS is a huuuuugeee libary and developers are staying away from it because it's not tree shaking

Comment: @JonasWilms: If you encountered this error and didn't know it was related to typing you would never find that response. It happened to me, and I wasted valuable time. I posted this question/answer to give someone else a head start :)

Answer (score 12):

The latest version of MomentJS now has defined types. Reinstall MomentJS without external typings. You should also avoid namespace-style import as such imports cannot be called or constructed and would cause a failure at runtime.

The way to go is traditional import:

`import moment from 'moment';`

Comment: @vidalsasoom so what? Self answering is a good thing